# Get all user with both meta_value

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, user-meta, users

I was wondering if there were any efficient way of fetching all user comparing two different meta_key. I am currently fetching all user compared to the first meta, then loop trough the user_id to compare the other meta. I actually need to count how many user have both values.
Ex : 
'MRC' => 'Mitis'
AND
'sellable_online' => 'true'

Answer (score 0):

Using the same structure as a meta_query, you can define a relationship to 'AND', but I think that's already the default. Please post a more structured example of your code so we can help you better.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/get_users